# Is there a way to find the startviewmodel in MVVMCross?

Tags: mvvmcross

I have done a `RegisterAppStart<FirstViewModel>()` in the Core App.cs, now I navigate to FirstViewModel, then  SecondViewModel and finally ThirdViewModel using `ShowViewModel()`,

*Is there a way I want to navigate to the `viewmodel` which has been registered using `RegisterAppStart<>()`, I mean is this persisted or saved somewhere during run?*

All I want is to get this value at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a singleton instance of a view model then you can do this using a custom view model locator - see the wiki - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Customising-using-App-and-Setup - "overriding view model location and construction"